# Contar Array usando sentencia Where en MongoDB y C#

Tags: c#, mongodb

en mi colección Alumnos tengo un arreglo en MongoDB de la siguiente manera:

```
"_id" : "fAFhzdtJ7wpJbdfbp",
"Nombre" : "Rastalovely",
"Materias" : [ 
    "ZNumksY9STZxc8a8W", 
    "W6BPzEwTaz9E7FxZB"
]
```

El campo Materias tiene una relación con la colección Materias, por ejemplo:

```
"_id" : "ZNumksY9STZxc8a8W",
"MateriaNombre" : "Matematicas"

"_id" : "W6BPzEwTaz9E7FxZB",
"MateriaNombre" : "Ingles"
```

Lo que necesito es mostrar en un combobox las materias que estoy cursando, ademas que me permita saber cuantas materias curso

> Mis avances

```
//Conexión con la Base
protected static IMongoClient cliente = new MongoClient();
protected static IMongoDatabase base = cliente.GetDatabase("base");
var coleccion = base.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("alumnos");
var filtro = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("_id", parametro);// le envio el id del alumno
var cursor = coleccion.Find(filtro);
var listado = cursor.ToList();
foreach (var item in listado)
   {
     ComboBox1.Items.Add(item["Materias"]);
     ComboBox1.DisplayMember = item["Materias"].ToString();
     ComboBox1.ValueMember = item["_id"].ToString();
   }
   //dentro de mi foreach me muestra el id de mis materias, pero no su nombre ademas de que no encuentro la forma para contar las materias
```

De esta manera cuanto cuantos alumnos existen

```
var collection = base.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("alumnos");
var query = Query.Empty;
var cuantos = collection.FindAs<BsonDocument(query).SetLimit(1).Count();
```

Answer (score 0):

Se me ocurré que dentro de tu foreach, podrías hacer una consulta a tu collección de materías.

```
var Materia = base.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("materias");

foreach (var item in listado)
{
    var query = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("_id", item._id);
    var materia = Materia.Find(query);
    // ahora agregas la materia con su nombre al combo box
    ComboBox1.Items.Add(item["Materias"]);
    ComboBox1.DisplayMember = item["Materias"].ToString();
    ComboBox1.ValueMember = item["nombre de la materia"].ToString();
}
```

Disculpa por los errores en C#, aún no ocupo algún driver para mongodb, pero esa es la idea.